# Using a custom comparator for std::map on IBM i-Series

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to use a std::map where the keys are c-style strings rather than std::strings but am having problems getting it to compile on an IBM iSeries targetting v7r1m0

I'd like to use c-style strings because using the Performance Explorer (PEX) it appears that the creation of lots of temporary strings for the purpose of map lookups is very expensive.

To do this I have used a custom comparator but when compiling on the iSeries I get an error:

> "/QIBM/include/t/xtree.t", line 457.30: CZP0218(30) The call does not
>     match any parameter list for "const mycompany::myapp::cmp_str::operator()".
>   "/QIBM/include/t/xtree.t", line 457.21: CZP1289(0) The implicit object
>     parameter of type "mycompany::myapp::cmp_str &" cannot be initialized with an
>     implied argument of type "const mycompany::myapp::cmp_str".

My comparator is defined as:

```
struct cmp_str 
{
    bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b)
    {
        return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};
```

and used in a map :

```
class LocalSchema : public RecordSchema
{
    public:
        int Operation;
        //map<string, int> FieldLookup;
        map<char *, int, cmp_str> FieldLookup;
};
```

Am I doing something stupid?

EDIT:
 changing to

```
std::map<char const*, int, cmp_str>
```

gives the same error. Looking in to the job log further I see that this error was produced while processing the following function:

```
inline int VxSubfile::IndexOfFieldInSchema(char * columnName)
{
    std::map<char const*, int, cmp_str>::iterator iter = _fieldLookup.find(columnName);
    if(iter == _fieldLookup.end())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        jdebug("Returning index : %d", iter->second);
        return iter->second;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens, if you make the `operator()` function `const`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
map<char *, int, cmp_str>
```

to

```
std::map<char const*, int, cmp_str>
```

that is, with `std::`, and with `const`.

**Edit**: Also make the comparison member function `const`, i.e.

```
struct cmp_str 
{
    bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b) const
    {
        return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};
```

---

Note 1: IBM's C++ compilers are infamous for being non-conforming in subtle ways, so you may still run into problems.

Note 2: You need to ensure that the strings outlive the map. E.g. you can use a `vector<unique_ptr<char const[]>>` as owner for the strings, allowing you to clean up.

Comment: I get the same error. I'm updating the question with some more detail.

Comment: @AndrewJones: So did I when I used Visual C++ (but not g++ which I tested with originally). So *maybe* a `const` is required by the standard. I added example to the answer.

Comment: That's cracked it. Thanks